# Opening outside pdf link inside Android webview(Java)

Tags: java, android, jsp, pdf, webview

In my JSP file -

```
windows.open("pdflink.pdf","_self");
```

I am calling the JSP file inside webview.After performing some operation,there will be a button.On button click it should open the above url.Does not matter inside webview or not.
I have tried modifying the with **Google PDF viewer** in .jsp and .java file both.But it is not working.

Any solution on this?
I am thinking of getting out of the webview and then open the pdf. But as a newbie don't have much idea.
A little help with link/code is much much appreciated.

Tried using Google pdf viewer.But not sure about windows.open() method.